# Bibtex source in JabRef

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I am using [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) to manage my bibliography. I also edited it to have extra table entries in the such as `SpecialRemarks` . However, I don't want these to appear in my bibtex source. So, my bibtex source is as follows:

```
@ARTICLE{XYZS2009,
  author = {X, Y and Z, S},
  title = {köuhr wqeröih wefdäkljwer oakwed },
  journal = {Elsevier},
  year = {2009},
  volume = {34},
  pages = {2051--2062},
  number = {12},
  doi = {10.1016/j.energy.2008.08.022},
  file = {:C$\backslash$:blblblblblblbl},
  issn = {03605442},
  keywords = {1d thermo-fluid dynamic models,diesel oxidation catalysts,diesel particulate
    filters,doc,dpf},
  publisher = {XYZ Ltd},
 url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask},
 SpecialRemarks = {skljfc lökasd äplasd  üpasd}

}
```

And with bibtex source I mean, the tab shown in the figure:

[image]

I don't want the `timestep`, `file`  and `keywords` ...to appear in the bibtex source. The best way to do that in my opinion, is to add an extra table entry, say `BibSourceShort`, which will contain only relevant bibtex entrix that I can copy directly to my `*.tex` project.
So I finally get only:

```
@ARTICLE{XYZS2009,
  author = {X, Y and Z, S},
  title = {köuhr wqeröih wefdäkljwer oakwed },
  journal = {Elsevier},
  year = {2009},
  volume = {34},
  pages = {2051--2062},
  number = {12},
  doi = {10.1016/j.energy.2008.08.022},
  issn = {03605442},
  keywords = {1d thermo-fluid dynamic models,diesel oxidation catalysts,diesel particulate
    filters,doc,dpf},
  publisher = {XYZ Ltd},
}
```

Does any one know how to do that?

Comment: you might want to look into building your own [export filter](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/help/CustomExports.php) for JabRef.

Comment: How did you define the ‘SpecialRemarks’ field? It isn't defined in any the bibstyle I know of. That said you can either save the bib files in two versions (with and without, if there are not too many entries). Or you can do a Search and Replace with `regular expressions` to remove automatically the irrelevant entries.

Comment: @Bernard you can do that through `Options-->Preferences-->Entry table columns`and use the `+`button to add the fields you are interested in.

Comment: I'm confused: the 'bibtex source' _is_ the `.bib` file: you can't add stuff in JabRef and not have it in the file. As commented by others, this data will almost certainly not appear in your bibliographies as the fields will be ignored by BibTeX. WE probably need to know what you are actually after here to have a hope of helping.

Comment: Like greyshade, I would suggest looking into export filters. Another option is to save your bibtex file and then run it through something like [bibtool](http://www.gerd-neugebauer.de/software/TeX/BibTool/index.en.html) to strip out unwanted fields.

Comment: @JosephWright: one possible use-case (not necessarily that of the OP), is that sometimes one does not want all collaborators to see those 'SpecialRemarks' one might write in one's own bibliography management software.

Comment: @WillieWong Yes, I can see that but that would be more 'I want to make a _copy_ of my BibTeX database which omits certain fields: what is the fastest way to achieve this?' or something of that type.

Comment: @JosephWright the bibtex source of each entry is directly available in the JabRef GUI

Comment: @user2536125 Following edit: As I've tried to indicate in my previous comment, the 'BibTeX source' _is_ the content of the file. All of the other tabs are simply a 'cleaner' way to view the same data. If you want to add something to the BibTeX file it _will_ be in the source. As Willie has mentioned and I replied, if you want a _copy_ of the file with some data removed that is quite doable but does need a second file.

Comment: @user2536125 I use JabRef also, and the additional fields in the database such as owner or timestamp don't disturb or cause any problem when you compile your .bib file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A BibTeX database is a plain text file (`.bib` file): JabRef provides a convenient and powerful editing front-end but cannot store data in the file without it being in the source. As such, if you add custom fields to the database they will be in the `.bib` file and so JabRef will show them in the source tab (which is meant for low-level editing).

It is of course possible to make a *copy* of a database file and remove some data. To remove fields, JabRef offers `Set/clear/rename field` on the `Search` menu. For example, to remove the `keywords` field in a copy of a database you would use:

[image]

As I say, this *modifies the database* so should only be done on a *copy* (unless you really want to 'kill' some useless data).